# Difference bwtween heavier than and weightier than

Tags: adjectives, translation

It's from this question.

[Can "he" and "man" refer to all genders?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/238232/)

> The ancient Chinese writer Si Maqian said, "Though death befalls all men alike, it may be **weightier than Mount Tai** or lighter than a feather." To die for the people is **weightier than Mount Tai**, but to work for the fascists and die for the exploiters and oppressors is lighter than a feather.

And I've found another adjective and it's very similar to this.

> heavier than

What's the difference between them?

Is "weightier than" also an old English as man refers all genders?

Because I've found nobody uses "weightier" on "blackhole", everyone says "heavier than a blackhole," and "heavier than" also works on "Mountun Tai" too.

> To die for the revolution is **heavier than** Mount Tai.
>
> ... is even **weightier than** a blackhole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a meaningful difference in their literal meaning.

In contemporary use you would almost always use "heavier" when describing the literal weight of an object.  You might use "weightier" if speaking in more metaphorical or philosophical terms, such as the weight of an important decision.