# The word "man" being used as "a person"

Tags: word-choice

Do some people care of or not happy of "a man" being used as "a person" in some sentence?

Comment: Do you care? I don't.

Comment: See [Can "he" and "man" refer to all genders?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/238232/can-he-and-man-refer-to-all-genders)

Comment: [So some people care whether etc.] care of makes no sense  here. You can use **mind**: So some people mind when a man is used for a person?

Comment: I am not clear whether the question is 'How many people will I annoy if I write 'a man' all the times when 'a person' is also correct?', or the reverse.

Comment: Or whether you use the word **man** while referring to both men and women. If that's the case, you may be sure that some people would mind. **Man** is sometimes used to refer to **mankind**, as in:: **God created a beautiful world; man has despoiled it.**  While this passes for some, others would rephrase it.

Comment: At my church, they change the words of well-known hymns to avoid using the words _man_ or _brother_. I'm all for using inclusive language in new writing, but I find it irritating not to be able to sing familiar words from memory!

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few people now object to the use of male forms as generic forms, including the use of "man" to mean person. Others do not. This was once very common in English us usage. it is now, I believe, considerably less common, but it does still occur.

A better answer would be possible with more specific context, including one or more actual example sentences.

Comment: It has fascinated me, as a native English speaker living in Portugal, to discover that if parents  here have a daughter, they have a **filha**. If they have four daughters in a row, they have four **filhas** but if the fifth child is a boy, they have five **filhos** (boys, to mean chlldren**. In my experience, such language rules favouring the male gender irritate Portuguese women rather less than they might their sisters in the English-speaking world.